# Seeking Guidance: overlapping video projection on cut tube

Tags: texturing, uv, camera

I hope you’re all doing well! I’m currently working on a project and could use some guidance on a particular aspect.

I have a cut tube where I plan to project two videos using overlapping projectors on its inner surface. Unlike real-time mapping tools, I’m aiming for a simpler solution that involves playing pre-rendered videos on each projector using the most cost-effective hardware available.

Specifically, I’m looking to achieve to get two correctly distorted and slightly overlapping videos that perfectly fit the projectors’ surfaces.
I’d appreciate any advice or suggestions on how to achieve this effect using Blender (or any other easily accessible tools, if there’s a simpler way). My primary aim is to learn and solve this problem.

Thank you all for your help in advance!

Best regards,
limestone

[image: quad view of my setup]

Comment: 1. What do you need this for? It will help others understand your problem. For example, do you make some kind of a simulation, that shows how an image, cast by two projectors, will look when displayed on a curved surface, and what the overlapping color will produce? Or contrary, do you want to find some kind of a setting to divide a video to two, and then use two projectors to maximize the surface used while minimizing deformation of projected video? 2. Why yellow projector is above blue projector, if it's displaying on bottom, i.e. why the projector frustums cross each-other?

Comment: 3. *"perfectly fit the projectors’ surfaces"* - what is a *projector surface*? Can you define it clearly? 4. *"slightly overlapping videos"* - could you point it in more objective terms, as we don't see the actual overlap on the screenshot? The Front Orthographic view kind of looks like there's close to 50% overlap, I wouldn't call it "slight".

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! English is not my first language, sorry. I will try my best to describe it better: 
1. Yes, I want to find a setup to divide a source video into two video streams for the projectors to maximise the surface and correct for the deformation of the tube in blender. 
2. This is defined by the physical mounting of the projectors some else does. But you are right, I will talk to him to find another solution so minimise overlap from the beginning of the beam.
3. By projectors surface I mean the two images the projectors are throwing.

Comment: There could be a reason for such mounting, e.g. it makes both projectors further away from the surface, allowing for larger coverage.

Comment: ad 3. The two images should perfectly match - maybe with a slight (soft?) overlap in the renders. By overlap I meant the overlap of the two video streams that overlap at the tubes surface, not the beam actually overlapping from the start.
4. see image here: https://imgur.com/a/O41H8u7
The projectors are short-throw. Maybe that's why he came up with this mounting solution. I will have to check